# Integrate $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1}$ along $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Integrate $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1}$ along $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi$. How to calculate this integral? I can show that $f$ has a primitive since its integration against any closed curve s zero.

Comment: How? it does not enclose its poles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $F(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \log\left( 1 - \frac{1}{z}\right) - \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)$. Then $F$ is holomorphic on the region $|z| > 1$ and satisfies $F'(z) = f(z)$. So

$$ \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = F(-2) - F(2) = \log 3. $$

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you explain the problem in another answer in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with logarithms, care should be taken with the argument.

Since $\frac1{z^2-1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}\right)$, the residue of $\frac1{z^2-1}$ is $\frac12$ at $z=1$ and $-\frac12$ at $z=-1$. With a branch cut along $[-1,1]$, all closed paths circle both singularities an equal number of times. Thus, independent of the path taken, we can define
$$
\begin{align}
f(w)
&=\int_2^w\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2-1}\\
&=\frac12\int_2^w\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}\right)\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac12\log\left(\frac{w-1}{w+1}\right)+\frac12\log(3)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
From $(1)$, we get $\arg(f(w))$ is $\frac12(\arg(w-1)-\arg(w+1))$. That is, $\arg(f(-2))=0$. Plugging in $w=-2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
f(-2)
&=\frac12\log\left(\frac{-2-1}{-2+1}\right)+\frac12\log(3)\\
&=\log(3)\tag2
\end{align}
$$